# ImportError: cannot import name 'RetriesExceededError' from 's3transfer.exceptions' (.../s3transfer/exceptions.py)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3, botocore

I consistently keep getting this error, regardless of:

- `boto3` version
- `boto3` imports and invokcations
- Environment my code is in.

I've attempted:

- Different functions after `client`
- `pip uninstall boto3 botocore` and `pip install boto3 botocore`
- `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel --user python`
- Reinstalling and isolating venvs

---

Code:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')  # <- Error
```

Traceback:

```
(venv) me@laptop:~/BitBucket/project$ python app/imagedx_container/app.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/BitBucket/project/app/imagedx_container/app.py", line 3, in <module>
    slide_ids, tile_filenames = download_tiles(bucket, slide_ids, tiles_dir)
  File "/home/me/BitBucket/project/app/imagedx_container/app.py", line 15, in download_tiles
    client = boto3.client('s3')
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/boto3/__init__.py", line 92, in client
    return _get_default_session().client(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 299, in client
    return self._session.create_client(
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 976, in create_client
    client = client_creator.create_client(
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 141, in create_client
    cls = self._create_client_class(service_name, service_model)
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 194, in _create_client_class
    self._event_emitter.emit(
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 412, in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 256, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 239, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/boto3/utils.py", line 65, in _handler
    module = import_module(module)
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/boto3/utils.py", line 56, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 16, in <module>
    from boto3.s3.transfer import (
  File "/home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/boto3/s3/transfer.py", line 128, in <module>
    from s3transfer.exceptions import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'RetriesExceededError' from 's3transfer.exceptions' (/home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/s3transfer/exceptions.py)
```

```
(venv) me@laptop:~/BitBucket/project$ pip show s3transfer
Name: s3transfer
Version: 0.6.0
Summary: 
Home-page: 
Author: 
Author-email: 
License: 
Location: /home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by: boto3

(venv) me@laptop:~/BitBucket/project$ pip show boto3
Name: boto3
Version: 1.26.101
Summary: The AWS SDK for Python
Home-page: https://github.com/boto/boto3
Author: Amazon Web Services
Author-email: 
License: Apache License 2.0
Location: /home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: botocore, jmespath, s3transfer
Required-by: 

(venv) me@laptop:~/BitBucket/project$ pip show botocore
Name: botocore
Version: 1.29.101
Summary: Low-level, data-driven core of boto 3.
Home-page: https://github.com/boto/botocore
Author: Amazon Web Services
Author-email: 
License: Apache License 2.0
Location: /home/me/miniconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: jmespath, python-dateutil, urllib3
Required-by: boto3
```

Answer (score 0):

`s3transfer==0.4.0` is a stable version, known to work with (currently the latest) `boto3==1.26.101` and it's dependency `botocore==1.29.101`.

Solution

```
pip install s3transfer==0.4.0
```

Comment: I will accept answer in 48hrs